# Habilitar CORS no cabeçalho da requisição

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api, angular

alguém sabe se tem como habilitar CORS no cabeçalho da requisição ajax sem ter que fazer nada no servidor da API, parecido com que o POSTMAN faz.
Com o POSTMAN as você testa a API e funciona certinho, quando vai para a aplicação de front da erro de CORS, então existe uma maneira de fazer isso pela requisição.

Comment: Os aplicativos do chrome podem ter permissões de cross domain. Quando você instala o postman, o aplicativo informa que ele terá acesso a qualquer domínio.

Comment: Fonte: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr até onde conheço, é necessário que seu servidor aceite CORS

Comment: Dependendo do que você quer, é possível usar um proxy.